# Lightning Experience Pass Parameters to reports encode issue

Tags: lightning, urlhacking, custom-link, salesforce-classic

Hi I have a report with filter say Account.Name = 'Test Account', for Dynamic reference for different Accounts I created a URL like below

```
reportId?pv0={!Account.Name}
```

To use this in Lightning I need to replace pv0 to fv0 when I did this the URL encode takes space as + which is expected, but passes the Same to the Filter value.

for Example if Account Name  is  "Test Account" the filter value returns to be "Test+Account", because of this the report is not returning any result.

Please let me know if any of faced the same problem.

Comment: how are you forming the url? can you try using encodeURIComponent() function in your lightning controller function and try to pass the account name ?         var url_val = "/one/one.app#/sObject/00Od0000004AYPFEA4/view?a:t=1495057260375&fv0="+encodeURIComponent(account_name);

Comment: yes, I did the Same, see for ex my URL is like this /one/one.app#/sObject/00Od0000004AYPFEA4/view?fv0={!URLENCODE(account.na‌​me))

Comment: can you post your component and controller code?

Comment: No, i am creating a custom link with type URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting %2B with %20.

Looks like space is getting converted to + and + gets encoded as %2B. Instead of encoding just let the url convert the space to + and substitute + with space

```
/one/one.app#/sObject/00Od0000004AYPFEA4/view?fv0={!SUBSTITUTE(Account.Name, "%2B", "%20") }
```

I tested this and the URL resulted to:

/one/one.app#/sObject/00Od0000004AYPFEA4/view?fv0=test%2034%2023&a:t=1495063836386

[image]

Comment: No luck, i tried this erlier, now I have tried again, /one/one.app#/sObject/00Ow0000006qBDUEA2/view?fv0={!SUBSTITUTE('test Account',"%2B","%20")}  still adding " +"  even I replaced the %2B with + still no luck

Comment: It worked fine for me, how abt you just put in the merge field and try with the substitute function.

Comment: I tried all those options ! I dont know where im missing!!!

Comment: Are you building this as a detail page link on the object? What is ur resulting url when you click the detail page link?

Comment: yes it is a detail page link , heres how it looks, after loading properly, it substitues %2B since + is substituted. one/one.app#/sObject/00Ow0000006qBDUEA2/view?fv0=test%2BAccount

Comment: Why does your url still show %2B instead of %20 after using substitute function on the text string??

Comment: Thats what the problem is!!! It is overriding whatever there!!

Comment: can you post a screen shot of the custom link? The links render fine and the report works as expected for me. I am curious to know if it some window behavior / browser behavior that might cause this. Did you try on a different browser to see how the space/ + / %20 all behave the same?

Comment: 00Ow0000006qBDUEA2/view?fv0={!SUBSTITUTE(Account.Name,"%2B","%20")} . Same nothing more!!! no luck